# Oracle: Does enabling a PK rebuild its index?

Tags: oracle, index, constraint

Scenario:

- Table `MY_TABLE` has primary key constraint `PK_MY_TABLE`
- Table `MY_TABLE` has also an index called `IDX_PK_MY_TABLE` which is enforces the uniqueness for constraint `PK_MY_TABLE`.

If I disable constraint `PK_MY_TABLE` and then enabled it back, does index `IDX_PK_MY_TABLE` get rebuilt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easily tested.

There are two possible scenarios.

**Scenario 1:**

Scenario 1 is creation of a PK using an existing index:

```
SQL> create table MY_TABLE
  2  (
  3  pk number
  4  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Add the index to it:

```
SQL> create unique index IDX_PK_MY_TABLE on MY_TABLE (pk);

Index created.

SQL>
```

Add the constraint:

```
SQL> alter table MY_TABLE add constraint PK_MY_TABLE primary key (pk) USING INDE
X  IDX_PK_MY_TABLE;

Table altered.

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints;

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
PK_MY_TABLE

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> select index_name
  2  from user_indexes;

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
IDX_PK_MY_TABLE
```

Insert some data:

```
SQL> insert into MY_TABLE values(1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into MY_TABLE values(2);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Test the constraint:

```
SQL> insert into MY_TABLE values(2);
insert into MY_TABLE values(2)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (PHIL.PK_MY_TABLE) violated

SQL>
```

Disable the constraint:

```
SQL>
SQL> alter table MY_TABLE disable constraint PK_MY_TABLE;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Try the `INSERT` again:

```
SQL> insert into MY_TABLE values(2);
insert into MY_TABLE values(2)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (PHIL.IDX_PK_MY_TABLE) violated
```

It succeeds because the unique index hasn't been disabled/dropped when the constraint was disabled. Note that the original error was     `ORA-00001: unique constraint (PHIL.PK_MY_TABLE) violated`, whereas the index constraint `PHIL.IDX_PK_MY_TABLE` is violated once the PK constraint is disabled.

**Scenario 2:**

Scenario 2 is creation of the PK upon table creation:

```
SQL> create table MY_TABLE
  2  (
  3  pk number,
  4  constraint PK_MY_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (pk)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> select index_name from user_indexes;

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
PK_MY_TABLE

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints;

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
PK_MY_TABLE

SQL>
```

Disable the constraint:

```
SQL> alter table MY_TABLE disable constraint PK_MY_TABLE;

Table altered.

SQL> select constraint_name, status from user_constraints;

CONSTRAINT_NAME                STATUS
------------------------------ --------
PK_MY_TABLE                    DISABLED

SQL>
```

The index has gone!:

```
SQL>  select index_name from user_indexes;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Re-enabling it recreates the index:

```
SQL> alter table MY_TABLE enable constraint PK_MY_TABLE;

Table altered.

SQL> select index_name from user_indexes;

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
PK_MY_TABLE

SQL>
```

If you want to keep the index:

```
SQL> alter table MY_TABLE disable constraint PK_MY_TABLE  keep index;

Table altered.

SQL> select index_name from user_indexes;

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
PK_MY_TABLE

SQL>
```

Answer (score 4):

Depends on how you disable the constraint.

```
 alter table my_table modify primary key disable;
```

The above drops the index, so when you enable the constraint, the index will be rebuilt. The below preserves the index:

```
alter table my_table modify primary key disable keep index;
```

If you disable the constraint this way, the index remains usable, and there will be no need to rebuild it when re-enabling the constraint.

Comment: There is one more case when the index will be not removed if PK constraint is disabled-  if it's not unique : `create table temp_test (id int not null , constraint pk_temp_test  primary key(id) using index (create index IDX_PK_TEMP_TEST ON temp_test(id))
);  alter table temp_test disable constraint PK_TEMP_TEST`

Comment: @a1ex07 It would be nice if you add that as a separate question to complement this. It would not certainly be accepted but would be undoubtedly upvoted. And it would be also easier to read.

Comment: Great answer. If you add rows to the table while primary key is disabled but the index is kept, what happens when you enable the primary key back? Is the index updated just with the newly added rows or would it be rebuilt from scratch (or dropped/created again)?

Comment: @ Tulains Córdova : Added as an answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Unless I miss something, the behaviour of dropping index together with disabling constraint depends on how the index is created and whether it's unique.
1.  Unique index created at the same time as constraint will be dropped when constraint is disabled unless `KEEP INDEX` is used

```
CREATE TABLE table1(table1_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);  
--or 
CREATE TABLE table1(table1_id INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE1 PRIMARY KEY(table1_id) ) ;    
--or
CREATE TABLE table1(table1_id INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE1 PRIMARY  KEY(table1_id) 
USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDXU_TABLE1_ID ON TABLE1(table1_id))) ;  
--or 
CREATE TABLE table1(table1_id INT NOT NULL );
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE1 
 PRIMARY KEY(table1_id) USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDXU_TABLE1_ID ON TABLE1(table1_id));
```

2. If unique index  exists before constraint is created, it'll be kept unless `DROP INDEX` is used.

   `CREATE TABLE table1(table1_id INT NOT NULL );
   CREATE INDEX IDXU_TABLE1_ID ON TABLE1(table1_id);
   ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE1 
   PRIMARY KEY(table1_id) USING INDEX IDXU_TABLE1_ID;`
3. If unique constraint is supported by non-unique index, the index will be kept unless `DROP INDEX` is used. E.g.

`CREATE TABLE table1(table1_id INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE1 PRIMARY  KEY(table1_id) 
    USING INDEX (CREATE INDEX IDX_TABLE1_ID ON TABLE1(table1_id))) ;`